# What is the time complexity for a nested loop in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I'm trying to tokenize a text file. I created a list of lines found in the text file using readlines() and plan to loop through each sentence in that list to split each sentence using re.split(). I then plan to loop through the resulting list to add each word into a dictionary to count how many times each word occurs. Would this implementation of a nested list result in O(N^2) or O(N)? Thanks.

This code is just an example of how I plan to implement it.

```
    for sentence in list:
        result = re.split(sentence)
        for word in result:
            dictionary[word] += 1
```

Comment: You tagged [python-3.x] and.. why not show a python code?

Comment: Sorry, just added some code. I haven't actually implemented it so I didn't have code to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for sentence in list: # n-times (n = length of list)
    result = re.split(sentence)
    for word in result: # m-times (m = number of words in sentence)
        dictionary[word] += 1
```

so runtime will be n * m or n-squared.

A better way to solve a counting problem is by using collections.Counter.